# Excel vba selection.copy destination does not paste properly

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I want to create a new workbook and copy some data from an already-opened workbook (Filename) and paste it into the new workbook. I have the following vba code:

```
Workbooks.Add
Set new_wb = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("pivot").Range("A28").Activate
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=new_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
```

However, I do not see anything pasted into the new workbook. Thus, I was wondering if I was doing anything wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `Select` and `Activate`:

```
Workbooks.Add
Set new_wb = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("pivot").Range("A28").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=new_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works perfectly. Do you mind explaining where exactly my code went wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't activate a cell in a non-active workbook, so I really expected your code would have crashed on the `Range("A28").Activate`.  Assuming somehow that line didn't crash out your code (maybe you have an `On Error Resume Next` that you didn't mention in the question?), the active cell would still be in the new workbook, so you were trying to copy blank cells.

Comment: Oh yes, I do have an `On Error Resume Next`. Now I see where I was wrong, thanks for your explanation!